# How do I grep for words with an exact number of occurrences of a letter?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to write a script that searches a dictionary for words that contain exactly two occurrences of each letter. I just don't the syntax to grep for exactly two occurrences of a letter.

Comment: Please give us an example.

Comment: Would this do: `grep '\([[:alpha:]]\{2\}\)[^[:space:]]*\1'` Thing is... you can't grep for the words only. You will get the whole line. If you only want the word how about using perl? `perl -Mopen=locale -lne 'print $& while /\S*([[:alpha:]]{2})\S*\1\S*/g'`

Comment: That would probably work because this dictionary has 1 word per line. Another question: if i was doing a loop with each letter being $i, where would i input the $i? I’m a beginner if you can’t tell @Rinzwind

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find exactly two instances *anywhere* in a word, then you will need to allow for arbitrary non-matching strings before, between, and after the matching characters.

e.g. to find *whole words* that consist of exactly 2 instances of letter `q`, case-insensitively, in `/usr/share/dict/words`:

```
$ grep -wi '[^q]*q[^q]*q[^q]*' /usr/share/dict/words
Albuquerque
Albuquerque's
Qiqihar
Qiqihar's
```

If you're not limited to `grep` specifically, you might want to consider using `perl` where you can make use of the fact that, when evaluated in a scalar context, the `tr` command returns the number of transliterations e.g.

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/qQ/qQ/ == 2' /usr/share/dict/words
```

In a similar vein, with GNU awk, you could define the character of interest as the field pattern and test the number of fields:

```
gawk -vFPAT='[qQ]' 'NF==2' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: +1, In my ears the question sounds like the answer should be: `for i in {a..z}; do grep -wi "[^${i}]*${i}[^${i}]*${i}[^${i}]*" /usr/share/dict/words; done` :)

Comment: @pa4080 sure - but the OP should be expected to do *some* work - they said they did say *"I just don't the syntax to grep for exactly two occurrences of a letter"* after all...